# configure private openstack with juju

Tags: juju, openstack

We have a working openstack (grizzly) cloud and want configure juju to work with it.
I follows https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure. But I can not find "Juju Environment Config" in horizon/settings page (Only User Settings is available). The API Endpoints has services:

```
    Compute
    Network
    Image
    Volume
    EC2
    Identity
```

I also can download OPenStack RC file and EC2 Credentials
But what I should put in environments.yaml?
I got error when try to bootstrap:

```
ERROR failed to GET object provider-state from container juju-aced10adfad7e3020fbc207e0d70aee6
caused by: authentication failed
caused by: failed executing the request https://:/v2.0//tokens
caused by: Post https://:/v2.0//tokens: local error: record overflow
```

The auth_url is correct which I got from API Endpoints as well as OpenStack RC file.

Comment: I need remove .juju/environments/openstack.jenv otherwise any update in environments.yaml doesn't take effect. But know I get "RegionOne" does not allow access to all required services error due to no swift on this openstack

Comment: I think I need post this to OpenStack forum. I did enable "EABLE_JUJU_PANEL = True" in /etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings.py. But if anyone know how to work-around this by using OpenStack RC file and EC2 Credential package on Juju side (environments.yaml) let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some observations about your setup:

- The guide you were following is unfortunately outdated and incorrect in places. It refers using the Python version of [juju](https://launchpad.net/juju), not the currently supported and maintained [juju-core](https://launchpad.net/juju-core).
- Try removing your `environments.yaml` from `~/.juju` and also make sure you remove any `~/.juju/environments/*.jenv` (beware, that if you remove the `.jenv' file of a running environment, you are effectively cutting your access to that cloud from Juju). Then, run`juju init`, which will generate you a boilerplate`environments.yaml`, containing the annotated set of most supported provider/cloud-specific configuration settings, commented as needed to indicate their default values, if any.
- Here's a [very good guide](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-openstack.html) on setting up a Juju OpenStack environment.
- You shouldn't need to use EC2-compatible API and credentials, just your OpenStack ones, the same you use to login to horizon or through nova client.
- Using a file like the suggested OpenStack RC file, Juju can go with minimal configuration, taking all other settings through the exported environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But our OpenStack doesn't have swift component. What should I set for "control-bucket"?

Comment: Unfortunately, the openstack provider in juju-core currently *requires* Swift to be present and listed in Keystone as an endpoint. There are plans to make it possible to configure the compute and storage parts of an environment separately, so that the cloud doesn't need to have storage enabled, but it's not a priority presently. You're welcome to file a bug against juju-core, so at least the progress on it can be tracked: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core